# Creating a Userform that changes depending on the elements it should contain

Tags: excel, userform, vba

Below is part of the code used to create a chart in Excel:

```
    elements = 0
    For j = 1 To x - 1
        ans = MsgBox(Activity(j), vbYesNo, "Do you wish for this Element to appear in the Gantt Chart?")
        If ans = vbYes Then
            elements = elements + 1
            ActivityNew(elements) = Activity(j)
        End If
    Next j
```

The idea is that I have a list of `x-1` activities in the array `Activity()` only some of which need to be displayed on the chart. These are stored in `ActivityNew()` and the variable `elements` counts the population of this array.

At the moment I use a `VbYesNo` message box to loop through all the activities in `Activity()` and ask the user to decide which should be shown in the chart.

I would like to show all the activities on a Userform each with a tickbox to either include in `ActivityNew()` or not but I have no idea how to go about that.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Creating a userform, populating your `ActivityNew()` array from a series of checkboxes?

Comment: I have never used Forms before and I am still trying to get my head around it so I am struggling with everything. I can get a userform to appear when I need it to but I don't know how to feed it information (the `Activity()` array) or to draw information from it (the `ActivityNew()` array). I also do not understand how to add controls in vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how to manipulate UserForms ?

You can use this code to create an element :

```
Set TheTickBox = UserForm.Controls.Add("Forms.TickBox.1", Visible = True)

With TheTickBox
    .Left       'Beginning of the tickbox compared to the left side of the UserForm
    .Width
    .Top        'Beginning of the tickbox compared to the top of the UserForm
    .Height
    .Caption    'Change the displayed text
End With
```

So you could use something like this :

```
For j = 0 to x - 1
    Set TheTickBox = UserForm.Controls.Add("Forms.TickBox.1", Visible = True)
    With TheTickBox
        .Left = 10
        .Width = The_Width_You_Want
        .Top = 10 + j*The_Height_You_Want        
        .Height = The_Height_You_Want
        .Caption = activity(j)
    End With
Next j
```

At the end of your UserForm you could add a Button 'Validate' that goes through all the tickboxes, and checks the value you've given them:

```
Sub ButtonValidate_Click()
elements = 0

For each Ctrl in UserForm.Controls

    If Ctrl.Value = True Then
        ActivityNew(elements) = Ctrl.Caption
        elements = elements + 1
    End If

Next Ctrl

End Sub
```

Edit :

To create the UserForm, just click on 'Add UserForm' when right clicking on your project (in the VBA editor).
The code lines I have given you at the beginning will have to be written in the UserForm code box (right click on your UserForm -> Code) and the following in the normal code area :

```
Sub UserForm()
    UserForm.Show     'Here I suppose UserForm is the name of your UserForm
End Sub
```

And in the UserForm code box make sure that your sub has this name :

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ACTIONS
End Sub
```

Comment: That's cool but I am not certain how to create the userform in the first place. How do I create a userform to appear when needed and include the elements i tell it.

Comment: You can create a UserForm in the VBA editor, by clicking the option 'Add UserForm' in the menu.

Comment: I found this which is really nice : [Explanation on UserForms](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-controls.html)

Comment: I am afraid I still can't get it to work. I just get an empty userform. How do I get the code to communicate with the code of the macro that will call it? i.e. how will it know the values of `x-1` and `Activity()` and how will the values of `ActivityNew()` be transferred back to the macro?

Comment: Are your activity arrays global variables ? You should define them outside a Sub or Function, like `Public Activity() As String`

Comment: I've tried defining both arrays as global variables but I still get an empty form...

Comment: Have you checked that the name of the controls you use in the code are the same used in the graphical part ? Especially `UserForm1` instead of `UserForm` ?

Comment: It seems that the reason i got an empty form was because the checkboxes were being created **off** the form! It works now. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the simplified output below:

[image: An userform that allows activities to be selected]

To have the output:
1. You need to have user form with its property of list box MulitSelect set to 1.

The following are the codes:
In Userform module:

```
Private Sub ButtonOK_Click()
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim i As LoadPictureConstants
    Msg = ""
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then _
        Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbCrLf
    Next i
    MsgBox "You selected: " & vbCrLf & Msg
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    Me.Caption = "Select Activities"

    Call BuildActivityArray
    For i = 1 To 5
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Activity(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

In standard code module:

```
Sub ShowForm()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```